# Is it possible to render an Adsense Block as a custom field block in Drupal?

Tags: display-suite

I'm trying to add an adsense banner inside my content and Drupal's Adsense regular module doesn't do that. It can only add Adsense in one of my regions but none within articles. Would that be possible using [Display Suite](http://www.drupal.org/project/ds)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Block Inject](http://drupal.org/project/block_inject) to create an arbitrary region in your node body. Then place the adsense block in that region. (Please be aware of this [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1957216).)

On a page by page basis, you can also use [Insert Block](http://drupal.org/project/insert_block), but there are limitations.

Comment: Block Inject is not stable. I was asking about Display Suite.

Comment: Display Suite has an option of inserting blocks as fields. Would that be ok to add an Adsense Block with the help of DS?

Comment: I see no reason not to. It will not embed the block in your body, but you could certainly put it within the displayed fields.

Comment: Thank you! 
Body is just another field, that could be renamed as we please. I'm thinking about a content type with multiple text or textarea fields + images then insert the block somewhere in the middle of these. Did you ever try this solution on some of your projects?

Comment: No I have not. Editing such pages would require the splitting of body text over several input fields, which is fine for a controlled site. But when you are dealing with pages authored by other users, the complexity would not be user friendly. If you, or your editors, are aware of the editing requirements and willing to work with the multiple input fields for a single piece of content, it would probably work well.

Comment: Have you been using Block Inject on D7 before? I was wondering if that could actually be a faster solution. I know is in alpha stage and that makes me consider DS. But if it works and doesn't violate Google Adsense's TOS, I guess it should do.

Comment: I have just started using it, and testing has shown a couple of issues I am going to bring up on the issue queue. The major issue is the field length of the node_type and node_name fields in the block_inject table. If you enter too many content types when configuring the region, the fields truncate and throw an exception. I have increased the fields from varchar(36) to varchar(256) and it has corrected the problem. The adsense banner is inserted right after the second paragraph. if there are two or more paragraphs in your content body. Appears to work well.